# How to interpret lm() coefficient estimates when using bs() function for splines

Tags: r, regression, lm, spline, bspline

I'm using a set of points which go from `(-5,5)` to `(0,0)` and `(5,5)` in a "symmetric V-shape". I'm fitting a model with `lm()` and the `bs()` function to fit a "V-shape" spline:

```
lm(formula = y ~ bs(x, degree = 1, knots = c(0)))
```

I get the "V-shape" when I predict outcomes by `predict()` and draw the prediction line. But when I look at the model estimates `coef()`, I see estimates that I don't expect.

```
Coefficients:
                                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)                       4.93821    0.16117  30.639 1.40e-09 ***
bs(x, degree = 1, knots = c(0))1 -5.12079    0.24026 -21.313 2.47e-08 ***
bs(x, degree = 1, knots = c(0))2 -0.05545    0.21701  -0.256    0.805
```

I would expect a `-1` coefficient for the first part and a `+1` coefficient for the second part. Must I interpret the estimates in a different way?

If I fill the knot in the `lm()` function manually than I get these coefficients:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.18258    0.13558  -1.347    0.215    
x           -1.02416    0.04805 -21.313 2.47e-08 ***
z            2.03723    0.08575  23.759 1.05e-08 ***
```

That's more like it. Z's (point of knot) relative change to x is ~ +1

I want to understand how to interpret the `bs()` result. I've checked, the manual and `bs` model prediction values are exact the same.

Comment: Sorry, It was not on purpose, I thought maybe I could select both of them as valid.

Comment: Both answers are telling me the same thing in the end... however for myself I wanted to understand the why of why the coefficients differ so I can understand the logic.
Both answers lead to how to calculate to the actual coefficient values but for me Zheyuan gave me also an extensive explanation for the logic behind it and therefore it is my preffered answer.

Comment: Sorry for that @rbm

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I would expect a `-1` coefficient for the first part and a `+1` coefficient for the second part.

I think your question is really about **what is a B-spline function**. If you want to understand the meaning of coefficients, you need to know what basis functions are for your spline. See the following:

```
library(splines)
x <- seq(-5, 5, length = 100)
b <- bs(x, degree = 1, knots = 0)  ## returns a basis matrix
str(b)  ## check structure
b1 <- b[, 1]  ## basis 1
b2 <- b[, 2]  ## basis 2
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(x, b1, type = "l", main = "basis 1: b1")
plot(x, b2, type = "l", main = "basis 2: b2")
```

[image: basis]

Note:

1. B-splines of degree-1 are **tent functions**, as you can see from `b1`;
2. B-splines of degree-1 are **scaled**, so that their functional value is between `(0, 1)`;
3. a **knots** of a B-spline of degree-1 is **where it bends**;
4. B-splines of degree-1 are **compact**, and are only non-zero over (no more than) three adjacent knots.

You can get the (recursive) expression of B-splines from [Definition of B-spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline#Definition). B-spline of degree 0 is the most basis class, while

- B-spline of degree 1 is a linear combination of B-spline of degree 0
- B-spline of degree 2 is a linear combination of B-spline of degree 1
- B-spline of degree 3 is a linear combination of B-spline of degree 2

*(Sorry, I was getting off-topic...)*

Your linear regression using B-splines:

```
y ~ bs(x, degree = 1, knots = 0)
```

is just doing:

```
y ~ b1 + b2
```

Now, you should be able to understand what coefficient you get mean, it means that the spline function is:

```
-5.12079 * b1 - 0.05545 * b2
```

In summary table:

```
Coefficients:
                                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)                       4.93821    0.16117  30.639 1.40e-09 ***
bs(x, degree = 1, knots = c(0))1 -5.12079    0.24026 -21.313 2.47e-08 ***
bs(x, degree = 1, knots = c(0))2 -0.05545    0.21701  -0.256    0.805
```

You might wonder why the coefficient of `b2` is not significant. Well, compare your `y` and `b1`: Your `y` is  **symmetric V-shape**, while `b1` is **reverse symmetric V-shape**. If you first multiply `-1` to `b1`, and rescale it by multiplying 5, (this explains the coefficient `-5` for `b1`), what do you get? Good match, right? So there is no need for `b2`.

However, if your `y` is asymmetric, running trough `(-5,5)` to `(0,0)`, then to `(5,10)`, then you will notice that coefficients for `b1` and `b2` are both significant. I think the other answer already gave you such example.

---

Reparametrization of fitted B-spline to piecewise polynomial is demonstrated here: [Reparametrize fitted regression spline as piece-wise polynomials and export polynomial coefficients](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44739192/4891738).

Answer (score 19):

A simple example of first degree spline with single knot and *interpretation* of the estimated coefficients to calculate the *slope* of the fitted lines:

```
library(splines)
set.seed(313)
x<-seq(-5,+5,len=1000)
y<-c(seq(5,0,len=500)+rnorm(500,0,0.25),
     seq(0,10,len=500)+rnorm(500,0,0.25))
plot(x,y, xlim = c(-6,+6), ylim = c(0,+8))
fit <- lm(formula = y ~ bs(x, degree = 1, knots = c(0)))
x.predict <- seq(-2.5,+2.5,len = 100)
lines(x.predict, predict(fit, data.frame(x = x.predict)), col =2, lwd = 2)
```

produces plot [image]
Since we are fitting a spline with `degree=1` (i.e. straight line) and with a knot at `x=0`, we have two lines for `x<=0` and `x>0`.

The coefficients are

```
> round(summary(fit)$coefficients,3)
                                 Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)                         5.014      0.021  241.961        0
bs(x, degree = 1, knots = c(0))1   -5.041      0.030 -166.156        0
bs(x, degree = 1, knots = c(0))2    4.964      0.027  182.915        0
```

Which can be translated into the *slopes* for each of the straight line using the knot (which we specified at `x=0`) and boundary knots (min/max of the explanatory data):

```
# two boundary knots and one specified
knot.boundary.left <- min(x)
knot <- 0
knot.boundary.right <- max(x)

slope.1 <- summary(fit)$coefficients[2,1] /(knot - knot.boundary.left)
slope.2 <- (summary(fit)$coefficients[3,1] - summary(fit)$coefficients[2,1]) / (knot.boundary.right - knot)
slope.1
slope.2
> slope.1
[1] -1.008238
> slope.2
[1] 2.000988
```

Comment: Hi @rbm, thank you for your answer. I was wondering if the Std. Error values in the summary table need to be converted as well or they will be the same for the translated cofficients