# interpretation of the output of R function bs() (B-spline basis matrix)

Tags: r, matrix, bspline

I often use B-splines for regression. Up to now I've never needed to understand the output of `bs` in detail: I would just choose the model I was interested in, and fit it with `lm`. However, I now need to reproduce a b-spline model in an external (non-R) code. So, what's the meaning of the matrix generated by `bs`? Example:

```
x <- c(0.0, 11.0, 17.9, 49.3, 77.4)
bs(x, df = 3, degree = 1) # generate degree 1 (linear) B-splines with 2 internal knots
#              1         2         3
# [1,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000    
# [2,] 0.8270677 0.0000000 0.0000000    
# [3,] 0.8198433 0.1801567 0.0000000    
# [4,] 0.0000000 0.7286085 0.2713915    
# [5,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000   
# attr(,"degree")
# [1] 1
# attr(,"knots")
# 33.33333% 66.66667% 
#  13.30000  38.83333 
# attr(,"Boundary.knots")
# [1]  0.0 77.4
# attr(,"intercept")
# [1] FALSE
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "bs"     "basis"  "matrix"
```

Ok, so `degree` is 1, as I specified in input. `knots` is telling me that the two internal knots are at x = 13.3000 and x = 38.8333 respectively. Was a bit surprised to see that the knots are at fixed quantiles, I hoped R would find the best quantiles for my data, but of course that would make the model not linear, and also wouldn't be possible without knowing the response data. `intercept = FALSE` means that no intercept was included in the basis (is that a good thing? I've always being taught not to fit linear models without an intercept...well guess `lm` is just adding one anyway).

However, what about the matrix? I don't really understand how to interpret it. With three columns, I would think it means that the basis functions are three. This makes sense: if I have two internal knots `K1` and `K2`, I will have a spline between left boundary knot `B1` and `K1`, another spline between `K1` and `K2`, and a final one between `K2` and `B2`, so...three basis functions, ok.  But which are the basis functions exactly? For example, what does this column mean?

```
#              1
# [1,] 0.0000000
# [2,] 0.8270677
# [3,] 0.8198433
# [4,] 0.0000000
# [5,] 0.0000000
```

EDIT: this is similar to but not precisely the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37362738/1711271.). That question asks about the interpretation of the regression coefficients, but I'm a step before that: I would like to understand the meaning of the model matrix coefficients. If I try to make the same plots as suggested in [the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37364459/1711271), I get a messed up plot:

```
b <- bs(x, df = 3, degree = 1)
b1 <- b[, 1]  ## basis 1
b2 <- b[, 2]  ## basis 2
b3 <- b[,3]
par(mfrow = c(1, 3))
plot(x, b1, type = "l", main = "basis 1: b1")
plot(x, b2, type = "l", main = "basis 2: b2")
plot(x, b3, type = "l", main = "basis 3: b3")
```

[image]

These can't be the B-spline basis functions, because they have too many knots (each function should only have one).

[The second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37363943/1711271) would actually allow me to reconstruct my model outside R, so I guess I could go with that. However, also that answer doesn't exactly explains what the elements of the `b` matrix are: it deals with the coefficients of a linear regression, which I haven't still introduced here. It's true that that is my final goal, but I wanted to understand also this intermediate step.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi, well, no. The question is talking about the `lm` coefficient, I'm asking about the basis function. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37364459/1711271) doesn't explain what the single coefficients of the matrix are. If I make the same kind of plots suggested in the first answer, I get garbage (definitely not B-spline functions, since their max should be 1). [The other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37363943/1711271) is better, but still not exactly what I asked for. I edited the question to show why.

Comment: Oooh, wait! I got it! I'm gonna answer my own question, now I understood what that matrix is :)

Comment: First of all, apologies, I didn't notice you were the author of the answer, otherwise I would have addressed you as such. Maybe we have a different terminology for basis functions. For me basis functions are infinite-dimensional objects (functions), and your answer shows them. But the columns of the matrix `b` are, IMO, not basis functions, but the values attained by the basis functions in the sample points `x <- c(0.0, 11.0, 17.9, 49.3, 77.4)`. ctd..

Comment: ..ctd I think it's not exactly the same: as a matter of fact, if I repeat your plot in my case, it gets all messy (see my edited question). However, if I plot the B-spline functions not against the vector `x`, but against the vector of knots, then I get your same plot. In your answer, if I interpret it correctly, the sample points and the knots are identical, so this issue doesn't show up. In mine, however, they're not, and that's why my matrix `b` contains elements which are different from `0` and `1`. Maybe for you it was obvious that the 2 cases were identical, but I couldn't see it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The matrix `b`

```
#              1         2         3
# [1,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000    
# [2,] 0.8270677 0.0000000 0.0000000    
# [3,] 0.8198433 0.1801567 0.0000000    
# [4,] 0.0000000 0.7286085 0.2713915    
# [5,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000
```

is actually just the matrix of the values of the three basis functions in each point of `x`, which should have been obvious to me since it's exactly the same interpretation as for a polynomial linear model. As a matter of fact, since the boundary knots are

```
bknots <- attr(b,"Boundary.knots")
# [1]  0.0 77.4
```

and the internal knots are

```
iknots <- attr(b,"knots")
# 33.33333% 66.66667% 
#  13.30000  38.83333
```

then the three basis functions, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37364459/1711271), are:

```
knots <- c(bknots[1],iknots,bknots[2])
y1 <- c(0,1,0,0)
y2 <- c(0,0,1,0)
y3 <- c(0,0,0,1)
par(mfrow = c(1, 3))
plot(knots, y1, type = "l", main = "basis 1: b1")
plot(knots, y2, type = "l", main = "basis 2: b2")
plot(knots, b3, type = "l", main = "basis 3: b3")
```

[image]

Now, consider `b[,1]`

```
#              1
# [1,] 0.0000000
# [2,] 0.8270677
# [3,] 0.8198433
# [4,] 0.0000000
# [5,] 0.0000000
```

These must be the values of `b1` in `x <- c(0.0, 11.0, 17.9, 49.3, 77.4)`. As a matter of fact, `b1` is 0 in `knots[1] = 0` and 1 in `knots[2] = 13.3000`, meaning that in `x[2]` (11.0) the value must be `11/13.3 = 0.8270677`, as expected. Similarly, since `b1` is 0 for `knots[3] = 38.83333`, the value in `x[3]` (17.9) must be `(38.83333-13.3)/17.9 = 0.8198433`. Since `x[4], x[5] > knots[3] = 38.83333`, `b1` is 0 there. A similar interpretation can be given for the other two columns.

Comment: Thanks for writing this up! Hugely helpful

Comment: could you explain why you are dividing x values by their knots?  You say, "`the value must be 11/13.3 = 0.8270677, as expected.`", but I'm unsure why you are dividing these two values.

Comment: @Parseltongue it's simply the linear interpolation for x = 11 of the values (0, 0) and (13.3, 1). In the interval [0,  13.3], the basis function `b1` is linear, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Just a small correction to the excellent answer by @DeltaIV above (it looks like I can not comment.)

So in `b1`, when he calculated `b1(x[3])`, it should be `(38.83333-17.9)/(38.83333-13.3)=0.8198433` by linear interpolation. Everything else is perfect.

Note `b1` should look like this

`\frac{t}{13.3}I(0<=t<13.3)+\frac{38.83333-t}{38.83333-13.3}I(13.3<=t<38.83333)`