# R bs function, explanation of the values

Tags: r

I try to understand how R obtain the values of the basis matrix with bs function. 
For example I create a vector :

```
A=c(1, 2,3)
```

And use the follow command

```
bs(A, knots = c(1,2 3), degree=1)
```

And I obtain this values

```
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
```

Can anyone explain how this values are obtained?

Comment: Include the package name for `bs()` function.

Comment: @Shree I guess it's ``splines``.

Comment: @tony napora Have you take a look at the function description? ``?bs`` and ``?splineDesign`` explains pretty well what they are doing.

Comment: Sry Shree is in the splines package

Comment: Yes Gainz I understand that the value is obtained via linear interpolation, thx  to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39446842/interpretation-of-the-output-of-r-function-bs-b-spline-basis-matrix. But I cannot reached the same value..