# Export fitted regression splines (constructed by 'bs' or 'ns') as piecewise polynomials

Tags: r, regression, lm, spline, polynomials

Take for instance the following one-knot, degree two, spline:

```
library(splines)
library(ISLR)
fit.spline <- lm(wage~bs(age, knots=c(42), degree=2), data=Wage)
summary(fit.spline)
```

I see estimates that I don't expect.

```
Coefficients:
                                  Estimate  Std. Error   t value    Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)                           57.349   3.950   14.518   < 2e-16 ***
bs(age, knots = c(42), degree = 2)1   59.511   5.786   10.285   < 2e-16 ***
bs(age, knots = c(42), degree = 2)2   65.722   4.076   16.122   < 2e-16 ***
bs(age, knots = c(42), degree = 2)3   37.170   9.722    3.823  0.000134 ***
```

Is there a way to extract the quadratic model (and its coefficients) for before and after the knot? That is, how can I extract the two quadratic models before and after the cut point of `age = 42`?

Using `summary(fit.spline)` yields coefficients, but (to my understanding) they are not meaningful for interpretation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was constantly asked to wrap up the idea in my original answer into a user-friendly function, able to reparametrize a fitted linear or generalized linear model with a `bs` or `ns` term. Eventually I rolled out a small R package `SplinesUtils` at https://github.com/ZheyuanLi/SplinesUtils (with a PDF version package manual). You can install it via

```
## make sure you have the `devtools` package avaiable
devtools::install_github("ZheyuanLi/SplinesUtils")
```

The function to be used here is `RegBsplineAsPiecePoly`.

```
library(SplinesUtils)

library(splines)
library(ISLR)
fit.spline <- lm(wage ~ bs(age, knots=c(42), degree=2), data = Wage)

ans1 <- RegBsplineAsPiecePoly(fit.spline, "bs(age, knots = c(42), degree = 2)")
ans1
#2 piecewise polynomials of degree 2 are constructed!
#Use 'summary' to export all of them.
#The first 2 are printed below.
#8.2e-15 + 4.96 * (x - 18) + 0.0991 * (x - 18) ^ 2
#61.9 + 0.2 * (x - 42) + 0.0224 * (x - 42) ^ 2

## coefficients as a matrix
ans1$PiecePoly$coef
#              [,1]        [,2]
#[1,]  8.204641e-15 61.91542748
#[2,]  4.959286e+00  0.20033307
#[3,] -9.914485e-02 -0.02240887

## knots
ans1$knots
#[1] 18 42 80
```

The function defaults to parametrize piecewise polynomials in shifted form (see `?PiecePoly`). You can set `shift = FALSE` for a non-shifted version.

```
ans2 <- RegBsplineAsPiecePoly(fit.spline, "bs(age, knots = c(42), degree = 2)",
                              shift = FALSE)
ans2
#2 piecewise polynomials of degree 2 are constructed!
#Use 'summary' to export all of them.
#The first 2 are printed below.
#-121 + 8.53 * x + 0.0991 * x ^ 2
#14 + 2.08 * x + 0.0224 * x ^ 2

## coefficients as a matrix
ans2$PiecePoly$coef
#              [,1]        [,2]
#[1,] -121.39007747 13.97219046
#[2,]    8.52850050  2.08267822
#[3,]   -0.09914485 -0.02240887
```

You can predict the splines with `predict`.

```
xg <- 18:80
yg1 <- predict(ans1, xg)  ## use shifted form
yg2 <- predict(ans2, xg)  ## use non-shifted form
all.equal(yg1, yg2)
#[1] TRUE
```

But since there is an intercept in the model, the predicted values would differ from model prediction by the intercept.

```
yh <- predict(fit.spline, data.frame(age = xg))
intercept <- coef(fit.spline)[[1]]
all.equal(yh, yg1 + intercept, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

The package has `summary`, `print`, `plot`, `predict` and `solve` methods for a "PiecePoly" class. Explore the package for more.