# Individual age at peak velocity from linear mixed natural spline model

Tags: r, differential-equations, mixed-models, spline, cubic-spline

This thread continues with [Get subject-specific peak velocity and age at peak velocity values from linear mixed spline models](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65303707/4891738).

---

I am fitting a linear mixed effects model with a natural spline function for age. I would like to estimate age at peak velocity (apv - years) and peak velocity (pv - grams) for each person in the dataset by differentiating the spline terms. The model includes a random quadratic slope for age.

How can I estimate the person-specific apv and pv? I am using the `SplinesUtils` package.

Example data:

```
dat <- structure(list(id = c(1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1002L, 
    1003L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1005L, 
    1005L, 1005L, 1005L, 1005L, 1006L, 1006L, 1006L, 1006L, 1006L, 
    1007L, 1007L, 1008L, 1008L, 1008L, 1008L, 1008L, 1009L, 1009L, 
    1009L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1011L, 1012L, 1012L, 1012L, 1013L, 
    1013L, 1014L, 1015L, 1015L, 1015L, 1016L, 1016L, 1016L, 1016L, 
    1016L, 1017L, 1017L, 1018L, 1020L, 1020L, 1021L, 1021L, 1021L, 
    1021L, 1022L, 1022L, 1023L, 1023L, 1023L, 1023L, 1023L, 1023L, 
    1023L, 1023L, 1023L, 1023L, 1024L, 1024L, 1024L, 1024L, 1024L, 
    1025L, 1025L, 1025L, 1026L, 1026L, 1026L, 1026L, 1027L, 1027L, 
    1028L, 1028L, 1028L, 1028L, 1028L, 1028L, 1028L, 1029L, 1029L, 
    1029L, 1029L, 1029L, 1029L, 1030L, 1030L, 1030L, 1030L, 1030L, 
    1030L, 1030L, 1030L, 1031L, 1031L, 1031L, 1031L, 1032L, 1032L, 
    1032L, 1032L, 1032L, 1033L, 1033L, 1033L, 1033L, 1034L, 1034L, 
    1034L, 1034L, 1034L, 1035L, 1035L, 1036L, 1037L, 1037L, 1037L, 
    1037L, 1039L, 1039L, 1040L, 1040L, 1040L, 1040L, 1040L, 1040L, 
    1041L, 1041L, 1041L, 1041L, 1041L, 1041L, 1042L, 1042L, 1042L, 
    1042L, 1042L, 1042L, 1042L, 1043L, 1043L, 1043L, 1043L, 1044L, 
    1044L, 1044L, 1045L, 1045L, 1045L, 1045L, 1045L, 1045L, 1047L, 
    1048L, 1048L, 1049L, 1049L, 1049L, 1049L, 1051L, 1051L, 1052L, 
    1052L, 1052L, 1052L, 1052L, 1053L, 1053L, 1053L, 1053L, 1053L, 
    1054L, 1054L, 1054L, 1054L, 1054L, 1054L, 1054L, 1054L, 1056L, 
    1056L, 1056L, 1056L, 1057L, 1057L, 1058L, 1058L, 1058L, 1058L, 
    1058L, 1060L, 1060L, 1060L, 1061L, 1061L, 1061L, 1061L, 1061L, 
    1062L, 1062L, 1062L, 1062L, 1062L, 1063L, 1063L, 1063L, 1064L, 
    1064L, 1064L, 1064L, 1065L, 1065L, 1066L, 1066L, 1066L, 1066L, 
    1066L, 1066L, 1067L, 1067L, 1067L, 1068L, 1068L, 1068L, 1068L, 
    1068L, 1068L, 1068L, 1069L, 1070L, 1070L, 1070L, 1071L, 1071L, 
    1071L, 1072L, 1072L, 1072L, 1072L, 1072L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 
    1073L, 1074L, 1074L, 1074L, 1075L, 1075L, 1075L, 1075L, 1075L, 
    1075L, 1076L, 1076L, 1076L, 1077L, 1077L, 1077L, 1077L, 1077L, 
    1077L, 1078L, 1078L, 1078L, 1078L, 1078L, 1078L, 1078L, 1080L, 
    1080L, 1080L, 1080L, 1081L, 1081L, 1082L, 1082L, 1082L, 1083L, 
    1083L, 1084L, 1085L, 1085L, 1085L, 1085L, 1085L, 1085L, 1086L, 
    1086L, 1086L, 1087L, 1087L, 1087L, 1087L, 1087L, 1087L, 1087L, 
    1087L, 1088L, 1088L, 1088L, 1088L, 1089L, 1089L, 1089L, 1089L, 
    1089L, 1090L, 1090L, 1091L, 1091L, 1091L, 1091L, 1091L, 1092L, 
    1092L, 1092L, 1092L, 1092L, 1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 1094L, 
    1094L, 1094L, 1094L, 1094L, 1095L, 1095L, 1095L, 1095L, 1096L, 
    1097L, 1097L, 1098L, 1098L, 1098L, 1098L, 1098L, 1099L, 1099L, 
    1099L, 1099L, 1099L, 1099L, 1099L, 1099L, 1100L, 1100L, 1100L, 
    1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1103L, 1103L, 1103L, 1103L, 1103L, 
    1103L, 1103L, 1104L, 1104L, 1104L, 1104L, 1105L, 1105L, 1105L, 
    1106L, 1106L, 1106L, 1106L, 1106L, 1106L, 1106L, 1106L, 1106L, 
    1107L, 1108L, 1110L, 1111L, 1112L, 1117L, 1123L), y = c(1934.047646, 
    1075.598345, 1956.214821, 2000.38538, 2000.38538, 732.315937, 
    3119.86, 624.951231, 791.2764892, 1884.530826, 624.951231, 1047.57, 
    1047.57, 791.2764892, 1238.306103, 1555.042976, 2547.870529, 
    2547.870529, 2467.385, 1181.635212, 1181.635212, 565.306282, 
    2016.027874, 2016.027874, 712.6134567, 635.2537841, 2167.362267, 
    2575.574188, 2167.362267, 2480.028259, 2575.574188, 2875.363243, 
    1180.139938, 2828.037147, 3017.119362, 2722.940933, 2167.92, 
    2409.652458, 2245.442558, 724.1520328, 635.6034756, 1649.08326, 
    966.8182507, 865.2717723, 1570.23, 916.1300105, 1180.999973, 
    2351.32885, 2418.851707, 2290.038887, 2224.060562, 2509.52, 1174.589081, 
    1540.219376, 2692.26, 1300.899734, 1100.650177, 1786.628242, 
    1705.842979, 543.8596134, 1786.628242, 2115.374241, 2331.46, 
    875.949604, 2241.945103, 2319.666939, 2316.220234, 719.7139549, 
    2042.803307, 719.7139549, 1132.977503, 875.949604, 2316.220234, 
    1737.18, 1351.629826, 1291.44593, 1291.44593, 1108.26586, 1028.979719, 
    1291.44593, 2068.934227, 2440.784416, 1036.72, 894.6663704, 2449.184731, 
    1109.9, 672.9310664, 2072.320354, 2114.215416, 2114.215416, 1805.422001, 
    2461.18, 2101.374248, 2105.879, 1600.086481, 2866.84, 1600.086481, 
    2807.311, 3055.569931, 1600.086481, 2602.287521, 2690.007614, 
    620.5975037, 2608.4, 2722.3, 2713.66185, 2608.4, 1590.002, 2198.211, 
    2488.097725, 2198.211, 2322.616348, 2627.1, 2418.328346, 2601.661034, 
    531.7369251, 811.9494571, 884.31, 768.0526981, 652.1271248, 768.0526981, 
    2767.479, 1047.144354, 1047.144354, 1995.119, 1995.119, 707.6093158, 
    707.6093158, 1120.650104, 3036.591904, 3036.591904, 3081.86, 
    1193.583691, 2056.569244, 1823.155, 1238.948124, 2124.685, 887.20438, 
    1823.155, 2056.569244, 2056.569244, 2560.155342, 3095.923164, 
    3095.923164, 3003.729011, 2861.12, 2560.155342, 2735.26, 822.8209591, 
    1648.951, 1648.951, 1648.951, 822.8209591, 906.7692623, 582.787096, 
    1286.45, 797.2365359, 2566.770554, 2666.41, 2666.41, 2045.320816, 
    2401.21, 2401.21, 2583.2, 2581.32, 2622.357, 2581.32, 2588.462498, 
    442.433671, 1251.627064, 406.2565479, 2108.787437, 983.1101169, 
    2102.085403, 1155.713411, 1909.797131, 2871.55, 2711.07, 2883.22245, 
    2883.22245, 2711.07, 3027.103172, 3108.21537, 3007.87294, 3208.963631, 
    3108.21537, 2617.91, 2457.464466, 2890.51, 2698.48214, 2700.723, 
    2700.723, 2817.668579, 2700.723, 1349.90691, 1476.19994, 1552.95, 
    1349.90691, 925.8325004, 1258.28, 840.1875095, 2405.175911, 840.1875095, 
    1056.678543, 1571.936, 1210.89, 1210.89, 673.7005405, 687.7842464, 
    1016.86, 1217.866, 1493.791817, 2246.726913, 1054.821, 1054.821, 
    563.6580887, 1054.821, 1540.429863, 2209.006493, 1437.835186, 
    2191.308, 1412.128944, 2724.164597, 2791.705185, 2727.774208, 
    2070.451198, 866.7974147, 1661.082638, 2108.271309, 2411.515434, 
    2342.026085, 2071.06, 2258.321014, 1537.06, 760.6319065, 867.7596569, 
    1907.60466, 1770.658, 760.6319065, 912.8781966, 912.8781966, 
    912.8781966, 1257.222706, 2586.922356, 1608.28, 962.5674305, 
    1085.451181, 2539.218132, 2535.526085, 2561.60054, 1600.198, 
    2100.048149, 758.3851737, 758.3851737, 2643.373329, 367.7795143, 
    866.0683727, 718.5049658, 866.0683727, 1906.694649, 2291.48, 
    2190.560314, 744.1710777, 1498.981777, 2460.912292, 590.1345787, 
    2487.559135, 1855.601353, 660.9104843, 1116.08, 792.929533, 708.8373737, 
    2272.232933, 1801.729801, 2299.800095, 2272.232933, 2299.800095, 
    1895.828438, 1757.75, 1050.279345, 1757.75, 1326.09478, 1326.09478, 
    1633.119305, 1558, 1167.971405, 1828.16, 1788.571758, 2175.469, 
    1071.039494, 941.6030864, 2053.067215, 1461.02132, 1597.646778, 
    1885.321567, 2195.704372, 2195.704372, 1675.768558, 3157.550789, 
    1565.173126, 2195.704372, 3157.550789, 2404.836883, 2541.045593, 
    585.7223682, 2465.177761, 2678.462074, 500.3733997, 2465.177761, 
    781.342, 898.3551559, 2465.177761, 2465.177761, 1807.02, 1418.888027, 
    1797.36, 1807.02, 2200.06, 2218.369926, 2200.06, 1986.642735, 
    2088.292, 2069.139, 1507.901432, 2061.395798, 2075.164864, 2081.913219, 
    2081.913219, 483.8579493, 1857.88, 2578.772636, 1857.88, 1857.88, 
    1039.632153, 2288.28, 2288.28, 1831.349922, 2349.23, 933.1002788, 
    2626.298935, 1521.744, 933.1002788, 2626.298935, 1984.760715, 
    2450.333, 1732.339031, 1984.760715, 2731.9, 869.2320918, 1785.72, 
    1922.798, 3081.28, 1508.8, 2421.288597, 1922.798, 1268.074959, 
    1569.05, 1808.115, 1569.05, 1268.074959, 2165.724808, 2165.724808, 
    1808.115, 2084.149837, 2693.027184, 2464.489, 2607.653496, 1012.837271, 
    1012.837271, 2673.190872, 2635.290516, 2773.42, 2635.290516, 
    2654.772674, 2377.905655, 2679.014969, 2654.772674, 1226.40016, 
    1470.69, 1273.789799, 2294.926086, 1226.40016, 1470.69, 1273.789799, 
    1873.817, 2274.930534, 2317.429165, 959.1709613, 1328.159428, 
    1328.159428, 1328.159428, 959.1709613, 1630.28, 1610.54982, 2507.05302, 
    750.467966, 750.467966, 821.2255058, 802.8240452, 2829.47879), 
        age = c(31.54004107, 11.95071869, 27.88501027, 27.88501027, 
        25.07871321, 10.90759754, 25.70020534, 9.560574949, 11.17864476, 
        15.8384668, 9.560574949, 11.23613963, 14.01232033, 10.54620123, 
        12.89527721, 14.52977413, 24.96919918, 24.72005476, 23.95893224, 
        13.31690623, 11.52087611, 9.927446954, 22.10814511, 16.44353183, 
        10.90759754, 7.991786448, 17.26488706, 23.95893224, 15.66872005, 
        17.63723477, 24.72005476, 30.97330595, 11.52087611, 17.5633128, 
        30.11088296, 23.31279945, 17.26488706, 20.58590007, 28.27926078, 
        11.66324435, 9.927446954, 13.92744695, 11.20328542, 12.70362765, 
        13.52498289, 12.21355236, 13.80150582, 22.81724846, 39.3045859, 
        16.62696783, 22.63107461, 29.86447639, 12.54483231, 14.42299795, 
        34.27789185, 12.91170431, 12.25462012, 21.81245722, 21.81245722, 
        10.05065024, 23.6659822, 16.22450376, 28.74743326, 12.70362765, 
        35.43052704, 21.21013005, 19.28542094, 12.77207392, 16.59411362, 
        12.12867899, 11.29637235, 11.81930185, 19.04449008, 19.93429158, 
        16.14236824, 12.85420945, 13.21560575, 11.61396304, 11.85763176, 
        13.3798768, 17.42915811, 24.41341547, 13.08418891, 11.6659822, 
        24.41341547, 12.06297057, 10.22861054, 26.15468857, 21.71937029, 
        20.1889117, 12.60232717, 25.39904175, 30.72689938, 19.22245038, 
        14.45037645, 24.77207392, 13.47570157, 17.87816564, 27.52635181, 
        15.16221766, 19.68514716, 21.67282683, 9.062286105, 20.43805613, 
        21.67282683, 21.24024641, 20.70362765, 13.5687885, 17.13347023, 
        28.11498973, 24.16974675, 18.19575633, 27.73442847, 15.52361396, 
        20.70362765, 11.76728268, 10.98699521, 11.51540041, 9.902806297, 
        13.05407255, 8.703627652, 25.60164271, 10.59000684, 10.59000684, 
        14.45859001, 14.05886379, 10.88295688, 10.75427789, 10.59000684, 
        26.50513347, 18.83093771, 22.86379192, 11.8384668, 15.04449008, 
        15.42505133, 14.14099932, 28.06844627, 11.51540041, 14.66119097, 
        13.79055441, 15.37850787, 22.58179329, 22.86379192, 30.0752909, 
        21.85900068, 25.60164271, 15.29089665, 26.79534565, 11.68514716, 
        15.42505133, 15.58384668, 15.08555784, 14.11909651, 11.6659822, 
        10.21765914, 12.1670089, 10.50239562, 23.3045859, 15.92607803, 
        22.58179329, 16.65982204, 20.58590007, 39.3045859, 32.56947296, 
        16.90349076, 25.12799452, 17.88364134, 19.46338125, 8.736481862, 
        14.14099932, 8.736481862, 17.68104038, 14.54893908, 19.22245038, 
        12.98562628, 22.45311431, 18.83093771, 38.68856947, 26.50513347, 
        25.44010951, 28.70910335, 19.21697467, 30.0752909, 26.50513347, 
        29.45106092, 33.31690623, 16.68172485, 15.816564, 24.89801506, 
        15.816564, 18.7761807, 18.4366872, 19.45790554, 19.78370979, 
        14.98973306, 15.89869952, 29.06502396, 16.14236824, 10.74880219, 
        13.47843943, 10.5982204, 24.61875428, 10.74880219, 12.47364819, 
        16.95277207, 12.41889117, 13.44832307, 9.984941821, 9.451060917, 
        12.59137577, 13.38261465, 15.14852841, 21.65913758, 12.57494867, 
        12.40520192, 10.75701574, 15.16495551, 15.67419576, 22.52703628, 
        13.31143053, 16.71457906, 12.98288843, 32.16974675, 25.3798768, 
        30.57084189, 22.14647502, 11.43874059, 13.25119781, 18.48049281, 
        25.81519507, 24.78028747, 17.85626283, 27.70704997, 13.28952772, 
        8.703627652, 11.61396304, 35.04996578, 15.61943874, 8.703627652, 
        13.33333333, 10.56810404, 11.34017796, 13.5797399, 28.79671458, 
        12.56673511, 13.33333333, 12.55578371, 30.80082136, 23.63039014, 
        29.66461328, 13.25119781, 17.46748802, 8.703627652, 8.703627652, 
        21.21013005, 9.768651608, 13.46748802, 10.75427789, 13.24298426, 
        26.87474333, 27.43326489, 20.6899384, 10.0752909, 13.37713895, 
        28.38056126, 8.911704312, 24.62149213, 14.32443532, 10.24229979, 
        13.87268994, 10.54620123, 11.44421629, 21.68377823, 15.61943874, 
        27.97809719, 28.90075291, 28.90075291, 24.64339493, 14.32443532, 
        10.61190965, 15.8110883, 14.25051335, 14.25051335, 13.64818617, 
        26.05338809, 13.69746749, 23.98083504, 16.68172485, 20.42162902, 
        12.68172485, 11.51813826, 16.65982204, 14.32443532, 15.49897331, 
        35.04996578, 18.70225873, 17.47570157, 14.66666667, 26.83915127, 
        13.29226557, 18.14647502, 25.70020534, 14.67761807, 16.61601643, 
        9.812457221, 15.96714579, 24.41341547, 8.911704312, 17.61806982, 
        11.87953457, 11.80561259, 19.15400411, 17.61806982, 15.70704997, 
        12.35318275, 18.12457221, 16.8733744, 32.02464066, 32.02464066, 
        25.30047912, 16.13415469, 19.37850787, 26.50513347, 15.89869952, 
        13.79055441, 25.42368241, 16.05201916, 15.43874059, 9.158110883, 
        14.39014374, 22.12183436, 15.70704997, 15.35934292, 11.44421629, 
        28.45995893, 17.06502396, 14.39014374, 26.32991102, 12.38056126, 
        16.42436687, 13.37713895, 11.70978782, 17.62628337, 16.13415469, 
        17.61806982, 15.11019849, 14.09993155, 21.89185489, 13.80150582, 
        16.8733744, 17.73305955, 25.55509925, 14.75975359, 24.03559206, 
        14.36002738, 12.73100616, 16.09034908, 18.12457221, 15.11019849, 
        13.69472964, 23.03901437, 16.94182067, 15.70704997, 13.99315537, 
        21.89185489, 15.65776865, 19.25530459, 10.43394935, 12.72826831, 
        24.41341547, 24.25735797, 37.41820671, 37.41820671, 25.25393566, 
        24.78028747, 25.25393566, 37.41820671, 12.11772758, 14.19575633, 
        14.091718, 15.10746064, 13.16906229, 12.09856263, 13.3798768, 
        14.39014374, 36.3504449, 22.68035592, 11.21149897, 12.73100616, 
        13.34702259, 14.5982204, 11.31827515, 15.14579055, 15.44969199, 
        15.65776865, 12.12867899, 12.43531828, 12.72005476, 14.11909651, 
        24.25735797)), row.names = c(7L, 303L, 323L, 372L, 391L, 
    240L, 311L, 38L, 46L, 94L, 149L, 154L, 185L, 362L, 40L, 70L, 
    98L, 262L, 305L, 73L, 74L, 77L, 306L, 374L, 104L, 397L, 14L, 
    43L, 188L, 248L, 370L, 50L, 101L, 143L, 25L, 155L, 251L, 37L, 
    173L, 208L, 263L, 49L, 383L, 389L, 30L, 237L, 353L, 156L, 283L, 
    288L, 302L, 325L, 33L, 158L, 159L, 35L, 360L, 57L, 128L, 204L, 
    387L, 300L, 365L, 16L, 51L, 82L, 85L, 93L, 148L, 150L, 232L, 
    242L, 287L, 32L, 62L, 200L, 285L, 290L, 193L, 352L, 398L, 54L, 
    175L, 203L, 324L, 69L, 195L, 92L, 106L, 141L, 189L, 218L, 347L, 
    394L, 23L, 24L, 120L, 166L, 257L, 349L, 6L, 118L, 235L, 266L, 
    269L, 275L, 282L, 390L, 122L, 153L, 330L, 378L, 53L, 88L, 229L, 
    241L, 314L, 135L, 278L, 332L, 384L, 64L, 168L, 207L, 212L, 359L, 
    329L, 338L, 130L, 67L, 108L, 286L, 316L, 182L, 254L, 113L, 215L, 
    247L, 273L, 322L, 336L, 27L, 102L, 162L, 171L, 270L, 326L, 19L, 
    205L, 210L, 307L, 333L, 358L, 375L, 41L, 111L, 179L, 226L, 2L, 
    277L, 367L, 68L, 83L, 147L, 180L, 260L, 354L, 144L, 81L, 342L, 
    103L, 217L, 321L, 376L, 131L, 280L, 39L, 267L, 291L, 301L, 400L, 
    11L, 36L, 152L, 177L, 377L, 21L, 201L, 236L, 281L, 312L, 331L, 
    355L, 369L, 8L, 176L, 202L, 385L, 45L, 327L, 12L, 138L, 151L, 
    157L, 233L, 95L, 258L, 279L, 224L, 239L, 243L, 310L, 328L, 63L, 
    191L, 214L, 227L, 356L, 80L, 110L, 366L, 97L, 107L, 293L, 373L, 
    117L, 335L, 22L, 160L, 209L, 221L, 230L, 268L, 55L, 163L, 284L, 
    5L, 10L, 76L, 132L, 222L, 256L, 399L, 228L, 127L, 343L, 357L, 
    133L, 259L, 334L, 261L, 341L, 382L, 393L, 395L, 213L, 219L, 249L, 
    289L, 44L, 126L, 368L, 42L, 72L, 196L, 297L, 308L, 320L, 84L, 
    137L, 172L, 60L, 129L, 142L, 186L, 197L, 319L, 15L, 109L, 115L, 
    116L, 125L, 199L, 223L, 190L, 245L, 346L, 396L, 146L, 364L, 1L, 
    29L, 192L, 112L, 170L, 315L, 164L, 225L, 231L, 255L, 274L, 345L, 
    65L, 96L, 264L, 4L, 28L, 31L, 59L, 87L, 250L, 271L, 295L, 161L, 
    198L, 265L, 339L, 18L, 26L, 114L, 124L, 174L, 145L, 304L, 105L, 
    119L, 140L, 238L, 381L, 48L, 52L, 71L, 351L, 371L, 244L, 253L, 
    294L, 340L, 20L, 75L, 86L, 165L, 167L, 47L, 89L, 298L, 318L, 
    211L, 350L, 380L, 66L, 79L, 90L, 234L, 309L, 61L, 99L, 139L, 
    276L, 299L, 344L, 348L, 361L, 313L, 337L, 379L, 9L, 58L, 181L, 
    187L, 17L, 100L, 121L, 123L, 184L, 206L, 220L, 178L, 292L, 386L, 
    392L, 194L, 252L, 272L, 3L, 56L, 134L, 136L, 183L, 216L, 246L, 
    296L, 363L, 169L, 388L, 78L, 34L, 13L, 91L, 317L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code for fitting the linear mixed spline model:

```
    library(nlme)
    library(splines)
    library(tidyverse)

    nspline_model <- lme(y ~ ns(age, df = 3), data = dat, random = ~ poly(age, 2) | id)
```

This is code showing how I tried to calculate apv and pv for two individuals - but i get a negative value for pv, and an apv value of ~39 years

```
# LIST OF PERSON IDs
dat %>% distinct(id) %>% pull()

library(SplinesUtils)

(random_quadratic <- random.effects(nspline_model))
spl_population_unshifted <- RegSplineAsPiecePoly(nspline_model, "ns(age, df = 3)", FALSE)

# ID = 1001

(coef_1001 <- spl_population_unshifted$PiecePoly$coef) 
coef_1001[1, ] <- coef_1001[1, ] + random_quadratic[1, 1]
coef_1001[2, ] <- coef_1001[2, ] + random_quadratic[1, 2] + random_quadratic[1, 3]

spl_1001_unshifted <- spl_population_unshifted
spl_1001_unshifted$PiecePoly$coef <- coef_1001

(apv_1001 <- solve(spl_1001_unshifted, b = 0, deriv = 2)) 
(pv_1001 <- predict(spl_1001_unshifted, apv_1001, deriv = 1))

(apv_pv_1001 <- as.data.frame(cbind(apv_1001, pv_1001)))
(apv_pv_1001 <- apv_pv_1001 %>% top_n(1, pv_1001))

# ID = 1002

(coef_1002 <- spl_population_unshifted$PiecePoly$coef) 
coef_1002[1, ] <- coef_1002[1, ] + random_quadratic[2, 1]
coef_1002[2, ] <- coef_1002[2, ] + random_quadratic[2, 2] + random_quadratic[2, 3]

spl_1002_unshifted <- spl_population_unshifted
spl_1002_unshifted$PiecePoly$coef <- coef_1002

(apv_1002 <- solve(spl_1002_unshifted, b = 0, deriv = 2)) 
(pv_1002 <- predict(spl_1002_unshifted, apv_1002, deriv = 1))

(apv_pv_1002 <- as.data.frame(cbind(apv_1002, pv_1002)))
(apv_pv_1002 <- apv_pv_1002 %>% top_n(1, pv_1002))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: OP updated his question, replacing the random line (as used in [the previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65303707/4891738)) with a random quadratic after being informed by my initial answer. My answer is then renewed to accommodate that.

---

**New answer**

When using a random quadratic, specify it with raw polynomial instead of (the default) orthogonal polynomial, otherwise the resulting polynomial coefficients have a different interpretation.

```
nspline_model <- lme(y ~ ns(age, df = 3), data = dat,
                     random = ~ poly(age, 2, raw = TRUE) | id)
random_quadratic <- random.effects(nspline_model)
```

Then when using [SplinesUtils](https://github.com/ZheyuanLi/SplinesUtils), make sure you add coefficients correctly:

```
library(SplinesUtils)

spl_population_unshifted <- RegSplineAsPiecePoly(nspline_model, "ns(age, df = 3)", FALSE)

# ID = 1001

(coef_1001 <- spl_population_unshifted$PiecePoly$coef) 
coef_1001[1, ] <- coef_1001[1, ] + random_quadratic[1, 1]  ## age ^ 0
coef_1001[2, ] <- coef_1001[2, ] + random_quadratic[1, 2]  ## age ^ 1
coef_1001[3, ] <- coef_1001[3, ] + random_quadratic[1, 3]  ## age ^ 2
```

Then you can proceed:

```
spl_1001_unshifted <- spl_population_unshifted
spl_1001_unshifted$PiecePoly$coef <- coef_1001

(apv_1001 <- solve(spl_1001_unshifted, b = 0, deriv = 2)) 
(pv_1001 <- predict(spl_1001_unshifted, apv_1001, deriv = 1))

(apv_pv_1001 <- as.data.frame(cbind(apv_1001, pv_1001)))
(apv_pv_1001 <- apv_pv_1001 %>% top_n(1, pv_1001))
```

---

**Initial answer**

This was indeed puzzling but I finally had my head turned around. There is nothing wrong with our code; what we see is mathematically guaranteed. Note that:

`subject spline = population spline + linear line`

After taking 2nd derivative, we have (since the 2nd derivative of a linear line is 0):

`subject spline 2nd derivative = population spline 2nd derivative`

Therefore, the age at peak velocity (where the 2nd derivative hits 0) is identical for all subjects! However, the peak velocity is different between subjects.

If we expect to derive a different age at peak velocity we need a random quadratic rather than a random line in the model. But building statistical model is not a mathematical game, so we need think twice about it.

Comment: Thank you, how would you calculate these if the model had a random quadratic? I have edited my question to include this.