# Subject-specific age at peak velocity from linear mixed natural spline model with spline random effects

Tags: r, differential-equations, mixed-models, spline, random-effects

I am using a linear mixed effects model with a natural spline function for age to describe the trajectory of an outcome `y` (measured in grams) across time (`age` in years) in a sample of individuals. My model includes random-effects for splines (with fewer degrees of freedom than the fixed-effects splines).

I would like to estimate the subject-specific (person-specific) age at peak velocity from this model.

A [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65509039/individual-age-at-peak-velocity-from-linear-mixed-natural-spline-model) describes how to estimate the subject-specific age at peak velocity when the model contains a quadratic random-effects age term.

The code below provides the example dataset and shows how the model was fit, how the mean trajectory was plotted and how the mean velocity curve and mean age at peak velocity were calculated.

How can I estimate the age at peak velocity for each individual from this model?

```
# LOAD DATASET
library(RCurl)
dat <- read.csv(("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aelhak/data/main/data.csv"))

# FIT MODEL
library(nlme)
library(splines)
model <- lme( # linear mixed-effects model
  y ~ ns(age, df = 7), # FE: natural spline function for age with 6 knots
  random = ~ ns(age, df = 3) | id, # RE: natural spline function for age with 2 knot
  method = "ML", data = dat)

# PLOT MEAN FITTED TRAJECTORY CURVE
pred <- data.frame(age = seq(min(dat$age), max(dat$age), length = 100))
pred$pred <- predict(model, pred, level = 0)

library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data = pred, aes(x = age, y = pred)) + geom_line()
```

[image: Plot of mean trajectory]

```
# PLOT MEAN VELOCITY CURVE
library(SplinesUtils)
spl_population <- RegSplineAsPiecePoly(model, "ns(age, df = 7)")
plot(spl_population, deriv = 1)
```

[image: Plot of mean velocity curve]

```
# ESTIMATE MEAN AGE AT PEAK VELOCITY AND PEAK VELOCITY
(apv_mean <- solve(spl_population, b = 0, deriv = 2)) 
(pv_mean <- predict(spl_population, apv_mean, deriv = 1))
(apv_pv_mean <- as.data.frame(cbind(apv_mean, pv_mean)))
(apv_pv_mean <- apv_pv_mean %>% top_n(1, pv_mean))

# apv_mean = 14.09897 years
# pv_mean = 317.1267 grams
```

Comment: What is your question? You have listed what you have done and what you would like to do, but now what your question is.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question. I have edited to add a sentence at the end stating my question -> How can I estimate age at peak velocity for each individual from this model? I.e. I have calculated the mean but how do I get person-specific values